# EF Core: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, concurrency

I am trying to update some data coming from a web Api service (POST) request.

I have a Restaurant object that contains a list of tables in the restaurant.

With POST i'm trying to add a table in that list but i get an error about DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

There's not another method that is trying to update the same list.

Here's my code:

```
public class Restaurant: DomainObject
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virutal ICollection<Table> Tables { get; set; }

    public Restaurant() : this(Guid.NewGuid(), "X") { }

    public Restaurant(Guid id, string name) : base(id)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

```
public class Table: DomainObject
{
    public const int MaximumCapacity = 6;
    private int _currentCapacity = 0;

    public int TableNumber { get; private set; }
    
    public Guid RestaurantId { get; private set; }

    // public virtual ICollection<Consumer> Consumers { get; set; }

    public Table(Guid id, int tableNumber, Guid restaurantId) : base(id)
    {
        TableNumber = tableNumber;
        RestaurantId = restaurantId;
    }
    
    public Table(int tableNumber, Guid restaurantId) : this(Guid.NewGuid(), tableNumber,    restaurantId) {}
}
```

```
public class DomainObject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get;  private set; }
        
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

    protected DomainObject() { }

    protected DomainObject(Guid id)
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

```
    [HttpPost("tables/add/{numberOfTables}")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<Restaurant> AddTables(string numberOfTables) 
        => await _restaurantService.AddTables(numberOfTables);
```

```
    public async Task<Restaurant> AddTables(string numberOfTables)
    {
        var restaurant = await GetRestaurantFromDatabase();
        Console.WriteLine($"GET Restaurant: {restaurant.Name}, {restaurant.Id}, {restaurant.Tables}, {restaurant.ModificationDate}");

        restaurant.Name = numberOfTables;
        restaurant.Tables.Add(new Table(10, restaurant.Id));

        var updatedRestaurant = await _restaurantRepository.Update(restaurant);
        return updatedRestaurant;
    }
```

```
    public async Task<T> Update(T entity)
    {
        entity.ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var context=ContextProvider.GetDbContext();
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }
```

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
            .HasKey(restaurant => restaurant.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Table>()
            .HasKey(table => table.Id);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
            .HasMany(restaurant => restaurant.Tables)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(table => table.RestaurantId);
```

I tried to use virtual list but that not work's i think.

And i tried to use the OwnsMany method but that gives me the same error.

**Solution: I saved first the tables in database, and after added that tables into the tables list of restaurant before doing Update.**

Comment: Usually when you are doing either an Insert or Update and get the wrong number of rows returned it indicates you have a primary key in the table.  When you use Insert if the key already exists the row does not get changed and you need to use Update.  When you use Update and key does not exist you need to use Insert.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, in code that i provided it's seen that every table have a primary key and foreign key. This error i got even when the table was empty if that's the case. I think i can't use Insert because i want to Update the Restaurant that contains that list of tables after adding some tables.

Comment: How can you update a table that has nothing in it?  There is nothing to change.  You need instead to use insert.  Normally what you will do is to attempt to update or insert and then test if the number of row changed equal zero.  Than if zero do the opposite (insert or update).

Comment: @jdweng Could you please give a small code example for this case?

Comment: Add break point and see if error is occurring in the method OnModelCreating().  I found same error on web when executing .HasKey.  You keys mapping may be wrong.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you very much, i tried to first insert the tables to db and after that add that tables into the list of the restaurant to update it and it worked.